# ROS/Turtlebot Wiki: How to distinguish between computers

Tags: ros, groovy-turtlebot, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am setting up my Turtlebot (v1) today: installing Ubuntu 12.10, installing & configuring ROS, and I've run into an issue.

I am having difficulty distinguishing, in the Turtlebot wiki, between instructions (i.e. terminal commands) to be carried out/executed on the Turtlebot's netbook, and those to be executed on my desktop computer.

Is this just me, or has anyone else had difficulty with this? Is there something I've missed, or a way to tell which commands to execute on the netbook vs. desktop? Or, are all commands meant to be run on both devices?

Here is an example:
I did realize the instructions on the [Workstation Installation](http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot/Tutorials/groovy/Workstation%20Installation) page were meant for the desktop/workstation. However, step five on that page says to "Follow the same instructions for the [turtlebot debian install](http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot/Tutorials/groovy/Debs%20Installation).", which say to execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-turtlebot ros-groovy-turtlebot-apps ros-groovy-turtlebot-viz
```

and:

```
echo "source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
```

My understanding was that those commands were meant to be executed the Turtlebot's netbook. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance, ROS community.    :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59635/ros/turtlebot-wiki:-how-to-distinguish-between-computers/) by [tommytwoeyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/1653/tommytwoeyes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2013-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorials are correct. Only if you install `ros-groovy-turtlebot-viz`on the workstation, you will be able to run visual apps like rviz & dashboard on the workstation. Regarding the first two, though you may not need some packages like `turtlebot_teleop` (belonging to `ros-groovy-turtlebot-apps`) and `turtlebot_bringup` (belonging to `ros-groovy-turtlebot`) you need the package turtlebot_description on your workstation to visualize the robot model in rviz. So installing all 3 is recommended. Look at the list of packages and descriptions [here](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot), [here](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps) and [here](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_viz), you will get an idea.

And, `echo "source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc` is a basic installation step (necessity). Be it a robot or just a computer this must be done to point to source location.

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2013-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2